# ffmpeg Unknown input format: 'lavfi'

Tags: unix, ssh, ffmpeg

I tried to create such a test image video using ffmpeg device "lavfi", but my LTS Ubuntu told me:

> "Unknown input format: 'lavfi'"

I got that my ffmpeg seems to miss that device. **But how to fix this?**

i used this:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc=duration=120:size=1280x720:rate=30 test.mp4
```

Comment: @Juergen Of course you should show your command and the complete console output to see why exactly you get the message. Right now we can only guess.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard: As I am not the original author, I can not edit this post. What I tried to do was something like: ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "inputfile.webm,volume=1.5" -f webm outfile.webm -- I guess. And than I got "Unknown input format: 'lavfi'". I guess, aergistal is right, that my version of ffmpeg is to old ... but I tried this trick, because the normal method of increasing the volume is also not supported and I would need an even newer version. I hoped, that there would be a way to install the input demuxer as additional package or some other trick might bring it to life.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do a `ffmpeg -formats | grep lavfi` to see if it supports the format.

Your `ffmpeg` may be really outdated, try with a newer version. There's a [PPA for Trusty](https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/trusty-media) but it's recommended to [compile it yourself](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) from  the [git development branch snapshot](https://www.ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2). [Static builds](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) are also available.

Comment: Thanks for that info. I am a little reluctant, since I do not know, if a manual compilation will bring my Debian Wheezy into troubles. I guess, that I have to deinstall ffmpeg and maybe other packages to avoid clashes. I am rather unhappy, that Wheezy comes with a ffmpeg version that is that old! I have no good feelings and rather bad experiences with fiddling around on the multimedia software on this system, so I rather want to avoid manual installs, where I can not foresee the results ...

Comment: @Juergen I believe Wheezy supplied the old, counterfeit "`ffmpeg`" from a fork which lacks many features, not `ffmpeg` from FFmpeg. The compile guide does not install to the system, so it will not interfere with anything. I edited the answer to add a link to static builds if you prefer not to compile.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard: Thank you very much! I will look into it, as soon I have some more time for it. Maybe I will go with a static build or try a build and not install it directly unto the system. I just don't know, which inter-dependencies between ffmpeg and other tools/libs exist. --- BTW: Yes. I long ago suspected that the Wheezy version is a lame duck ... but without installing a totally new system, I have to stick with some inconveniences ....

Comment: @LordNeckbeard +1 for the "counterfeit ffmpeg" and thanks for the edits

Comment: @LordNeckbeard: I already tried the static build version -- and the results look really, really good. The option "-af volume=2" is accepted. I did not try the lavfi, since with the -af option there is no need for me any more. But it is listed with -formats, so I guess, it will work fine! *Thank you, very, very much!* Unless you open an own answer, I guess, the bounty will go to aergistal -- of course his contribution was also very good, but for me the static linked binaries are pure gold!

Comment: @Juergen Thanks, but you can just accept this answer.